# Python Turtle Spiral

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I wrote a program to draw a fractal and then draw a spiral. The spiral should follow a fibo pattern, and should be recursive in nature

Here's the code -

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import math

t = Turtle()
s = Screen()
t.speed(0)

def square(x, y, side):
    t.setpos(x,y)
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(side)
        t.right(90)

def tiltsquare(x, y, side):
    t.left(45)
    square(x, y, side)

def squareinsquare(x, y, side):
    square(x, y, side)
    half = side / 2
    b = math.sqrt(half**2 + half**2)

    tiltsquare(x, y - side/2, b)

#x,y are start coordinates, stLength is the length of first move and k is the number of moves
spiral(225, -120, 35, 5)


s.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing the initialization of `a` and `b`:

```
    a = 0
    b = 1
```

Here's a simplified version of the code with this fix:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from math import pi

def square(x, y, side):
    turtle.setpos(x, y)

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(side)
        turtle.right(90)

def fractal(x, y, startSide, k):
    turtle.setpos(x, y)

    for _ in range(k):
        square(*turtle.position(), startSide)
        turtle.forward(startSide / 2)
        turtle.right(45)
        startSide /= 2**0.5

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

fractal(0, 0, 200, 15)

# x, y are start coordinates and k is the number of moves

def spiral(x, y, k):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.setheading(45)
    turtle.pendown()

    a = 0
    b = 1

    for _ in range(k):
        distance = (pi * b * x / 2) / 90

        for _ in range(90):
            turtle.forward(distance)
            turtle.left(1)

        a, b = b, a + b

spiral(225, -120, 5)

screen.exitonclick()
```